# Regex - Remove everything from a string that does not match an expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am creating a JavaScript function that will take a user inputted value and and create a CSS class name out of it. The following expression can be used to detect whether the end result follows valid css rules

```
-?[_a-zA-Z]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*
```

but I need to find a way to use it to remove all invalid characters.

I was thinking of something like:

```
var newClass = userInput.replace(EVERYTHING BUT /[_a-zA-Z0-9-]/, "");
```

Comment: @burning_LEGION, thanks for the etiquette edit. Will keep in mind for future posts. Love the community on stackoverflow!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

A very small modification to your existing regex should work, using the `^` operator and `g`:

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/g
```

Which should be used as:

```
var newClass = userInput.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_]/g, '');
```

The `^` character, as the first character inside the brackets `[]`, specifies to match what's *not* in the brackets (i.e. - the characters you want to strip).
The `g` modifier performs a global-match on the entire input string.

Comment: I noticed that you changed the order of the characters in the expression. Any reason for that or just preference. It does help with readability mind you.

Comment: @MindWire Only my own personal preference; I like keeping the alpha-numeric characters first and symbols last (also how you'll find most regex examples online too). And yes, I think it helps with readability a lot too!

Answer (score 3):

```
var newClass = userInput.replace(/\W/, "");
```

\w equals to [a-zA-Z0-9_]

\W equals to [^a-zA-Z0-9_]

Comment: Missing the dash as a replaceable character, but nice job on explaining the \w \W feature.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't explain it better because that's the way my co-worker answered me. I saw the question and asked the one who knew so I could help the OP.

Answer (score 2):

`var result = userInput.replace(/[^\w-]/g, '');`